# Function for pytest parametrize is being called multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest parametrize for some of tests. Now the values of the parameters are being fetched from a function and likewise for the Ids. But I observed that the function is being invoked multiple times. I would expect it to be only called once. Sample code explaining the scenario :

```
def _get_test_run_configs():
    start_time = time.time()

    test_runs_list = # Some logic that gets the list (Its a list of tuple)

    test_case_names = _generate_test_case_names(test_runs_list, str(start_time))
    return test_runs_list, test_case_names


def _generate_test_case_names(runs_list: list, start_time: str) -> list:
    test_case_names = []
    for design, run, run_hash in runs_list:
        run.name = f"{run.name}_{start_time}"
        test_case_names.append(run.name)
    return test_case_names


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "design, run, run_hash", _get_test_run_configs()[0], ids=_get_test_run_configs()[1]
)
def test_run_game_day(design, run, run_hash):
    assert True
```

On running the test the test case names are appended with the following timestamps, which are all different :

> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753834]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753835]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753836]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753837]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753838]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753839]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753840]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753841]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753842]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753843]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753844]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753845]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753846]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753847]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753848]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753849]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753850]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753851]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753852]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753853]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753854]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753855]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753856]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753857]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753858]
> test_run.py::test_run_game_day[_1689738444.995753859]

My expectation is that the `_get_test_run_configs` should only be called twice. But it's being invoked multiple times. I verified this using the `start_time` that I am adding for the test names. Why is this happening and how do it fix this behavior.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. test_runs_list should not be an empty string but a list of triplets ?

Comment: @Gelineau - Yes, there a logic to get the list, I haven't pasted that here.